# Recursion Algorithm Flood Fill

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, flood-fill

Every time I run this I get a stack overflow and I know it is because the algorithm never reaches the base case. I also know that iteration is best used in this case but this has to be done recursively. Any tips, tricks or advice as to how to make it not overflow and still perform what it needs to is greatly appreciated.

```
def fill(cave, row, col, color):
    """Fill a chamber of the cave with water, starting
    at row, col. Water can spread in all four cardinal
    directions, but cannot penetrate stone.  No effect
    if row or col are not inside the cave.

    Attempting to pour water where there is already WATER or STONE
    has no effect.  Attempting to pour water outside the cavern has
    no effect.  Attempting to pour water in a cell containing AIR 
    not only places colored water in that cell, but also spreads it
    in all directions by causing it to be poured in the cell to the 
    left and right and above and below. 

    Args: 
        cave: A matrix (list of lists) representing the cavern. Each 
            cell in the cave may hold AIR, STONE, or WATER.
        row: Starting row of the grid cell where we pour water
        col: Starting column of the grid cell where we pour water
        color: color of the water we try to pour in.
    """
    caveWidth = len(cave)
    caveHeigth = len(cave[0])

    if cave[row][col] == STONE or cave[row][col] == WATER:
        return

    if row > 0:
        fill(cave, row-1, col, color) #left
    if row < caveWidth-1:
        fill(cave, row+1, col, color) #right
    if col > 0:
        fill(cave, row, col-1, color) #up
    if col < caveHeigth-1:
        fill(cave, row+1, col, color) #down

    if cave[row][col] == AIR :
        cave[row][col] = WATER
        grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data/invocation parameters for which you are observing the behavior?

Comment: Your down case has a bug. I think you mean fill(cave, row, col+1, color). Also a typo.. caveHeigth -> caveHeight

Comment: Can you also provide the implementation of the grid.fill_cell method?

Comment: You ruined your own chances for learning by doing this.  Putting print statements at the entry and return points and figuring out what was happening would have been a terrific exercise. Now you'll just take the answer of @Kolmar and miss the thrill and great benefit of figuring it out yourself. Such a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Set current cell to `WATER` **before** making recursive calls. Otherwise it can just keep bouncing on two neighbouring `AIR` cells infinitely.

```
if cave[row][col] == AIR :
        cave[row][col] = WATER
        grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)

if row > 0:
        fill(cave, row-1, col, color) #left
    if row < caveWidth-1:
        fill(cave, row+1, col, color) #right
    if col > 0:
        fill(cave, row, col-1, color) #up
    if col < caveHeigth-1:
        fill(cave, row+1, col, color) #down
```